# Reconciliation during Dataphor's registration of libraries

Tags: rdbms

When registering libraries in Dataphor what is the difference between registering with and without reconciliation?

In my experience from learning and using this DBMS we've always registered without reconciliation. What are some example cases where we may choose one option over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registering with reconciliation means that the Data Definition Language (DDL) statements will be run against the target device(s).  This is desired behavior when starting from a blank or non-existing database, where you want Dataphor to create the needed structures.  Otherwise, the preferred methodology is to register without reconciliation so that any existing database is ignored, and use the `DeviceReconciliationScript()` operator to reconcile the changes.